# Отправка запроса при помощи axios вместо jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, axios

```
function f1(){
var q = $('#four').val();
$.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json/" + q + "?callback=?",            function(data) {
    var table_body = "";
    $.each(data, function(k, v) {
        table_body += "<tr><td>" + k + "</td><td><b>" + v + "</b>   </td></tr>";
    });
    $("#GeoResults").html(table_body);
});
}
<input id="four"  type="text" onchange="f1()">
<table id="GeoResults"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function f2(){
        var q = $('#fice').val();
        var resultElement = document.getElementById('getResult1');
        resultElement.innerHTML='';
            axios.get("http://ip-api.com/json/" + q + "?callback=?")
                .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response)
            resultElement.innerHTML = generateSuccessHTMLOutput(response);
        })
            .catch(function (error) {
            resultElement.innerHTML = generateSuccessHTMLOutput(error);
        });
    }

    function generateSuccessHTMLOutput(response){
        return response.data
    }

<input id="fice"  type="text" onchange="f2()">
<div id="getResult1"></div>
```